# Plotly.js using two dollar signs in a title (without LaTex)

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm using the following title with Plotly.js

```
var title = "Price: $350k - 450k";
```

It will display something like the following `Price: $350k - 450k`

I want to do the following:

```
var title = "Price: $350k - $450k";
```

so I can get something like `Price: $350k - $450k` (hint: second $)

Apparently, in Plotly.js doing this enables LaTeX and causes it to become a mathematical expression (sort of).  I've tried using the \$ escape for LaTeX but it doesn't seem that Plotly.js or possibly MathJax.js supports this.

Sadly I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to add a second dollar sign to a chart.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `&#36;` to represent a dollar sign in the string appears to work for me. So the full string would likely be:

```
var title = "Price: &#36;350k - &#36;450k";
```

I tried this out here and got what you wanted: https://plot.ly/create/?fid=PlotBot:3. I don't have an account so I cannot say for sure.

Comment: Brilliant!  I apparently paradigmed on trying to get the escape sequence to be LaTeX instead of avoiding the $.  Thanks!